# Batch, Convert wget downloaded unindented html document To html with indented lines

Tags: html, windows, text, batch-file, wget

maybe this is a rare question...

I download a html for example with this command:

```
Wget http://mp3skull.com/mp3/coone_your_dj.html
```

And then, wget makes a html document without indentation, like this:

[image]

And i need a html document with indented lines and the right sintax like this:

[image]

I can do the manual conversions thanks to my text editor wich recognizes the syntax, Copying the first text (1st image) and then saving it to a new html file (2nd image), But i need something like an APP or a CODE to do this job automatic in BATCH.

There is something that can help me?

PD: My editor (Sublime Text) don't have console parameters.

PD 2: Copy images links and open it in a new browser window to see image's max size.

Thankyou.

Comment: Downloading mp3 files like that is illegal in some countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbeautifier.org/ does a great job on indenting html and xml tags aswell as javascript.

If you need to do it offline then [this](http://www.arachnoid.com/linux/beautify_bash/bash_beautify.rb.html) looks kinda promising.

Comment: i need to do it offline. i've tryed your 2nd suggestion but i receive this error i don't know how to use it for a entire html document: C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop>ruby 1.rb 1.html
1.rb:54: warning: character class has duplicated range: /.*<<-?\s*['|"]?([_|\w]+
)['|"]?.*/
1.rb:45:in `beautify_string': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x2608d70> (N
oMethodError)
        from 1.rb:139:in `beautify_file'
        from 1.rb:157:in `block in main'
        from 1.rb:156:in `each'
        from 1.rb:156:in `main'
        from 1.rb:166:in `<main>'